# Is conversion of some data type to a larger data type the same as arithmetic right shift?

Tags: c, c99, bit-shift, integer-arithmetic

This is a two fold question .

1. I have been reading up on the intricacies of how compilers process code and I am having this confusion.  Both processes seem to be following the same logic of sign extension for signed integers. So is conversion simply implemented as an arithmetic right shift?
2. One of the examples states a function as

   ```
   Int Fun1(unsigned word ) {
         Return (int) ((word << 24) >> 24 );
   }
   ```

   The argument passed is 0x87654321.
   Since this would be  signed  when converted to binary, how would the shift happen? My logic was that the left shift should extract the last 8 bits leaving 0 as the MSB and this would then we extended while right shifting. Is this logic correct?

Edit: I understand that the downvote is probably due to unspecified info. Assume a 32 bit big endian machine with two's complement for signed integers.

Comment: You are asking in regards to twos-complement?

Comment: `word` is declared to be `unsigned`, so should compile to a logical rather than arithmetic shift.  The conversion to a signed integer is performed after the shift.

Comment: If `int` is 32-bit then `0x87654321` has type `unsigned int`

Comment: @m.m. typo corrected

Comment: @neapolitan Thank you. I had missed the type of the argument. But even if the type is signed , does the logic remains the same, except the fact that the bits after shifting would be 1s(assuming the integer is negative ) instead of zeroes ?

Comment: The endian (big, little or otherwise) is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: example don't compile. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 1):

Given OP's "Assume a 32 bit ...  machine with two's complement for signed integers." (This implies 32-bit `unsigned`)

> 0x87654321 Since this would be signed when converted to binary

No. `0x87654321` is a hexadecimal constant.  It has the type `unsigned`.  It is not signed.

---

```
// Int Fun1(unsigned word ) {
int Fun1(unsigned word) {
      Return (int) ((word << 24) >> 24 );
}
```

`Fun1(0x87654321)` results in `unsigned word` having the value of `0x87654321`.  No type nor value conversion occurred.

`word << 24` has the value of `0x21000000` and still the type of `unsigned`.

`(word << 24) >> 24` has the value of `0x21` and still the type of `unsigned`.

Casting to `int` retains the same value of `0x21`, but now type `int`.

---

> So is conversion simply implemented as an arithmetic right shift ?

Doubtful, as no signed shifting is coded.  C does not specify how the compiler realizes the C code.  A pair of shifts, or a mask or a multiply/divide may have occurred.